# How Many Write Operation will be counted if Insert operation is done on parent entity?

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints

I am working on google cloud datastore using cloud endpoint. i have created Owned One-to-Many Relationships between Department and Employee using JPA annotation. Entities are:

```
Department(Parent)
   String Id
   String Name
   List Employee(@OneToMany)

Employee(Child)
   Key key
   String firstName
   String lastName
   String Address
   Department dept(@ManyToOne)
```

Code for Insert Operation Is:

```
    Departmentendpoint dptendpoint=null;
    Departmentendpoint.Builder builder1 = new Departmentendpoint.Builder(AndroidHttp. 
                          newCompatibleTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), null);
    dptendpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(builder1).build();

    Department dpt = new Department();
    dpt.setId("Dept1");
    dpt.setName("Safety");

    List<Employee> m = new ArrayList<Employee>(); 

    Employee mgr= new Employee();
    mgr.setFirstName("Devwrat");
    mgr.setLastName("Lad");
    mgr.setParentId(dpt.getId());
    mgr.setAddress("Mumbai");
    m.add(mgr);

    Employee mgr2= new Employee();
    mgr2.setFirstName("Avinash");
    mgr2.setLastName("Patel");
    mgr2.setParentId(dpt.getId());
    mgr2.setAddress("Surat");
    m.add(mgr2);

    dpt.setManager(m);
    try{
        dptendpoint.insertDepartment(dpt).execute();
    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Question

If I make a insert query "dptendpoint.insertDepartment(dpt).execute()" on parent entity how many write operation will perform?

thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I have asked same question to google channel partner and got below reply.

```
It will be like inserting into two entities.
```

So basically total write operation for ""dptendpoint.insertDepartment(dpt).execute()" query will be: 20 write operation. which is explainbelow:

```
For Department Entity:
     1 (for the entity itself) + 1 (for the EntitiesByKind index) + 2 * 3(for indexed property) + 1 * 0 (for composite index) = 8 write operation

For Employee Entity
     1 (for the entity itself) + 1 (for the EntitiesByKind index) + 2 * 5(for indexed property) + 1 * 0 (for composite index) = 12 write operation
```